# How to calculate time taken for an animator's animation to complete?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get the total time taken for an animator's animation to complete? Either in coroutines or in updates?

```
public class AnimatorLoop : MonoBehaviour {

     private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        StartCoroutine(PlayAnim());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator PlayAnim()
    {
        anim.Play("MoveForward", 0, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: why is this even an `IEnumerator`? Just make it a method...

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerator PlayAnim()
{
    anim.Play("CubeForward", 0, 0);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Debug.Log("current clip length = " + anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);
}
```

Just had to add one line mentioning the length, which calculates the distance and speed to give time.